# How I can use Global.asax for storing the authentication for separate user?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have made a static variable in global.asax

```
public static MemberManager.Member _CurrentUser;
```

The problem for me is it is shared with other request (another user can steal the authentication if they browse on same time of another). How I can fix this code by not share it with other request.To make it fix I Thing to clear Member just before the request and after the request complete.

```
 this.BeginRequest += ClearMember;
 this.AuthorizeRequest += MvcApplication_AuthorizeRequest;
 this.EndRequest += ClearMember;

  void ClearMember(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _CurrentUser = new MemberManager.Member();
        }
```

I thing to make it work by remove it just after completion of request and begining of request. I am unsure that it will work.

Someone can make sure that it will work. I didn't want to share my currentUser variable between request. Is this code make it work or not.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use static field for this. Static class fields are shared by all code (all threads) running in the same AppDomain. Store this object in Session:

```
public static MemberManager.Member _CurrentUser
{
  get
  {
    return (MemberManager.Member)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["__MemberManager_Member"];
  }
  set
  {
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["__MemberManager_Member"] = value;
  }
}
```

Comment: I didn't found namespace for Session, Is Member still share with other request even I start to clear the member before and after thr request ?

Comment: I updated the answer with `Session` taken from the current request context. Yes, it is still share, because requests from different users are processed in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you need to store authentication?

Use forms authentication. User will then send cookie with auth key upon every request.

Add attribute on login action so it allows anonymous calls:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public virtual ActionResult Login(string username, string password)
{
   //login logic here
}
```

In login action check for username and password, and if they're correct do:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, isCookiePersistent);
```

To log user out, call (i.e. in log out action)

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
```

When registering global filters, be sure to register "AuthorizeAttribute" like so:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{            
    filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
}
```

and you are done! User must be logged in for all calls, except the ones you decorate with "AllowAnonymous" attribute.

Edit: if you want to track currently logged in users, check caching. The most basic is "InMemory" but you can store the cache in a file, a separate process or even in a DB if you like.